# How to change array to object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have list of objects

```
[
    { regionName:'Alabama',code:'AL', value: 89 },
    { regionName:'Alaska',code:'AK', value: 112 },
    { regionName:'Arizona',code:'AZ', value: 101 },
    { regionName:'Arkansas',code:'AR', value: 123 }
]
```

which I want to convert to below format -

```
{
     AL: { value: 89  },
     AK: { value: 112 },
     AZ: { value: 101 },
     AR: { value: 123 }
}
```

How this can be achieved in JS?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason for the other object layer? If you are just going to have `value`, why not just have `AL: 89`? I'm guessing you will add to it later?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `map` method by passing a `callback` provided function as `parameter` which is applied for every item from the given **array**.

```js
let array=[ { regionName:'Alabama',code:'AL', value: 89 }, { regionName:'Alaska',code:'AK', value: 112 }, { regionName:'Arizona',code:'AZ', value: 101 }, { regionName:'Arkansas',code:'AR', value: 123 } ];

array = Object.assign(...array.map(({ code, value }) => ({ [code]: {value:value }})));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Really pretty nice :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) so on every iteration you append new `key` (AL, AK or AZ) into the final result.

```js
const arr = [
  { regionName:'Alabama',code:'AL', value: 89 },
  { regionName:'Alaska',code:'AK', value: 112 },
  { regionName:'Arizona',code:'AZ', value: 101 },
  { regionName:'Arkansas',code:'AR', value: 123 }
]
    
const result = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    [curr.code]: { value: curr.value },
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I am late but this should also work with simple  [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array_of_objects = [
    { regionName:'Alabama',code:'AL', value: 89 },
    { regionName:'Alaska',code:'AK', value: 112 },
    { regionName:'Arizona',code:'AZ', value: 101 },
    { regionName:'Arkansas',code:'AR', value: 123 }
];
var required = {};
var result = array_of_objects.map(function(obj){
  return (required[obj.code] = {value:obj.value});
})

console.log(required);
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "AL": {"value": 89},
  "AK": {"value": 112},
  "AZ": {"value": 101},
  "AR": {"value": 123}
}
```